# How to wait for asynchronous operation to complete before rendering every time state changes

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on an app that displays images that are dynamically generated by the backend in response to changes in the current state.

I only want a component to re-render after a state change after the asynchronous call to the backend has returned with the new image.

Then I want to atomically update the image (in a canvas, say) and other UI based on the state - e.g. some HTML.

If I was generating a new image synchronously on the client I could use a (Layout) Effect hook to update the canvas.

I could only change the state after the network request to the backend returns - but I'm not sure of the cleanest way of doing this. I have to copy a whole bunch of state (into a "pending" state) and then mutate a bit of it, send it to server and only apply it when the call returns? It could get a little complicated if there are multiple state changes in-flight at once. Then I need to continue to mutate "pending" state in response to subsequent actions.

I wonder - is there something in React (or Redux?) that can help with this? Or should I try code it up myself?

BTW I'm new to React.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically looking for async actions you can learn to do it natively [here](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions) or use a middleware like redux-thunk (or redux-saga but its a bit complicated to be honest).

The basics are for every async requests you need to make 3 actions

1. A action to start the request.
2. A action when the action completes.
3. A action if the request fails.

and the code will look something like

```js
function async makeRequest() {
  dispatch({type: 'START'})
  try {
    const res = await myRequest()
    dispatch({type: 'SUCCESS', payload: res})
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({type: 'FAILURE', payload: e})
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I read the link. It shows an example where data in backend is fetched. In my case I send updated state to a stateless backend and use it to compute the response. As suggested in question, I want to set the update state and render only when the response returns. But I need to handle multiple concurrent state changes and requests. So tracking the cumulative state changes before applying them seems tricky. Is there a tool or an idiom that might help me?

Comment: > I want to set the update state and render only when the response returns.

The code above is doing exactly that. 

> But I need to handle multiple concurrent state changes and requests. So tracking the cumulative state changes before applying them seems tricky.

It is, putting the every api in redux increases the amount of work quite a bit but IMO the payoff is huge.